# Eclipse Indigo on OS X Lion, Java 'source' hover not working

Tags: java, eclipse, osx-lion, eclipse-indigo

I'm running Eclipse Indigo on OS X Lion and it all seems to be working very well, except that I can't get the Java 'source' hover to work properly. Regardless of what I configure in the Java -> Editor -> Hovers section in Preferences the hovers I get are the following when hovering over a method name:

- **Hover with no modifier key pressed**: Javadoc (or message indicating no
  Javadoc available), despite the fact that the Javadoc hover is
  disabled.
- **Hover with Command key pressed**: popup menu allowing me to choose from
  Open Declaration or Open Implementation.
- **Hover with Shift key pressed**: should bring up the source of the method in a tooltip window, but brings up the Javadoc window instead (behaves as if no modifier key were pressed).

No matter what I do I can't get the 'Source' hover to work, even if that's the only hover action I have enabled and regardless of what modifier key I assign to it. This is a shame as the Source hover is by far the most useful IMO.

The problem doesn't occur with Indigo on Windows, so it appears to be an OS X specific issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further research it appears this is a known bug: [Eclipse Bug 357127](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=357127). Will be fixed in 3.7.2.